# multiply the values of the keys in the nested object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

need to Create a calculate function that accepts a bucket and products. a bucket is an object with parts that we are going to purchase, and items is an object with prices for parts from stores.

please explain how can I do it, expanded..

```
const bucket = {
  display: 100,
  wheel: 40,
  cpu: 80,
}

const items = {
  amazobot: {
    wheel: 20.5,
  },
  robozetka: {
    display: 36,
    cpu: 50.30,
  },
}

calculateCost(bucket, products) === 8374
```

what I have:

```
const calculate = function(bucket, products) {

  for (const key in products) {
    for (const prop in products[key]) {

    }
  }

};
```

Comment: how do you get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the 8374 is coming from. If I interpreted the question correctly, the result should be 8444, and this is the function to get it:

```
function calculate(bucket, products){
    let total = 0;
    for(const item in bucket){
        for(const market in products){
            if(item in products[market]){
                total += products[market][item] * bucket[item];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This basically executes: `100*36 + 40*20.5 + 80*50.30`

If this is not what you were trying to do, explain better what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the values of `items` and get the key/value of `bucket` to get a product and sum all products.

```js
const
    calculateCost = (bucket, products) =>
        Object.values(products).reduce((sum, object) =>
            Object.entries(bucket).reduce((s, [k, v]) => s + (bucket[k] || 0) * v,
            sum
        ),
        0
    ),
    bucket = { display: 100, wheel: 40, cpu: 80 },
    items = { amazobot: { wheel: 20.5 }, robozetka: { display: 36, cpu: 50.30 } };

console.log(calculateCost(bucket, items)); // 8374
```